Does anyone have a translated copy of Schevchenko's 1975 paper on interactions between killer whales and other cetaceans?
I am looking for a translated copy of this citation:
Shevchenko, V. I. "The nature of the interrelationships between killer whales and other cetaceans." Morskie Mlekopitayshchie Chast 2 (1975): 173-174.
I've put in a request with my university library, but I think that may take awhile.   This citation is commonly cited, but I can't find a digital copy.
Cheers!

My library did get back to me! If anyone wants to read this paper, it was translated by Canadian officials in 1976.
https://waves-vagues.dfo-mpo.gc.ca/library-bibliotheque/113316.pdf
It is published by Ste. Anne de Bellevue, Quebec : Arctic Biological Station, 1976. If the link is broken, search the Canadian Federal Science Libraries Network. The pdf is made available by DFO Dartmouth, NS.

Glad you found it, and thanks for a gripping and enjoyable read. In the end, the paper is a bit off topic as there's only bio and no acoustics in this paper. Not a criticism, just a heads up for anyone who may have been stumbled across this thread in the hopes that it contained information on bioacoustics.

No, you are right. It is just cited often in BA papers, which is why I was looking for it.  I can remove this post if we think it is too off topic.
